# ActiveMerchant specs fails to connect to API, while development mode works fine with same credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, activemerchant

I am trying to setup specs for my `Checkout::Sale` class that employs `ActiveMerchant` using credentials for a test Authorize.NET account that I set up the other day.

My plan was to use [VCR](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr) to record the response for the gateway and run my specs against that, so I'm not hitting the gateway all the time when I run my specs.

Here's is [my spec and my class](https://gist.github.com/1726125) that I'm testing.

My issue is, this code works perfectly if I'm am in the Rails console (development environment), but fails every time I run my specs (test environment). Specifically, the Authorize.NET API complains that my credentials are invalid...

> (TESTMODE) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account
>   is inactive.

... even though I use the exact same credentials in development and they work fine.

I have no `ActiveMerchant`-related logic in either `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/test.rb`.

I don't understand how the exact same code is working for me in development and not in test mode. Anyone know what's up with this?

I'm using `activemerchant 1.20.2`, `rspec 2.8.0` and `rails 3.1.1`.

NOTE: This fails regardless if I'm using VCR or not; removing VCR seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aph, just figured it out.

Just passing `test: true` only makes the transaction a test transaction, even though the gateway is still hitting the `:production` gateway.

As this test runs without Rails loaded, I wasn't loading in my environment files, where I had specified for both dev and test:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
```

Since loading the rails console does load Rails, that's why it was working in development but not in my tests. Throwing the above into a `before` block solved my problem.